# How to play sound _ during _ launch, not after launch in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, splash-screen

I've seen suggestions to play sound in:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

The latter being in AppDelegate.m.

These two methods, play a sound *after* the launch. I've tested it and it should be obvious from their names.

I would like to play either before or preferably during the launch. Is it possible? I've seen at least one popular app that looks like it does this, but it may be a fake out and instead just showed a black screen at start up.

Comment: honestly, I didn't get what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to application start during launch (AFAIK) is `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` , but frankly I don't know whether the app is prepared to play sound within. Just give it a try.